# How to present alert by code or in custom class in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have searched all document about how to present alert in swiftui, but they all show code like this:

```swift
Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
}) {
            Text("Show Alert")
}
.alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("title"))
}
```

Which means that alert must be used for button.

How can I use alert in my custom class like handle http request and then show error alert like this:

```swift
class A{
    func getDate(){
        alert("error")
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be possible somehow with dirty tricks, but why do you want to do that? wouldn't it be much cleaner and swiftier if you propagate your error to the top(to the view) and then the view shows the error?

Comment: IMO there *are* good reasons to do this. But if a `Button` isn't the "trigger", what is? I think something has to be - for instance a `View` method of `onAppear`. Another way - in your case using `class A` - make `getDate()` change a `@Published` variable and have the `View` that is interested in it subscribe the this variable.

Comment: @Chris Because in `View`, I want to call backend api to get data, and I write related code in custom class to handle them, but when api return error, I want to show error on the view.

Comment: @dfd Yeah, just like Schaheer's answer.

Comment: Yeah just change the @Published variable and the view will rerender itself causing the alert to show

Answer (score 3):

Create a class and conform to the `ObservableObject` protocol (Anything that conforms to ObservableObject can be used inside SwiftUI, and publish announcements when its values have changed so the user interface can be updated):

```
class A: ObservableObject {

    @Published var showAlert = false

    func buttonTapped() {
        //handle request and then set to true to show the alert
        self.showAlert = true
    }

}
```

Your View:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = A()

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            self.viewModel.buttonTapped()
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert, content: { () -> Alert in
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Please try again"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: I did just the same, but can't make it work. I can see log message on alert, however alert is not showed

Comment: Please check this line (it should be marked @Published):
@Published var showAlert = false

Comment: I have the similar method to address this issue. But I use the UIAlertController in my ViewModel instead of using Alert in ContentView.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it, if you want to use custom error description, then create your custom error which conforms to the `Identifiable` protocol like below:

```
enum NetworkError: LocalizedError, Identifiable {
    case notFound
    case serverError(responseCode: Int)
    case underlyingError(Error)
    case unknown

    var id: String { localizedDescription }

    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .notFound: return "Not found"
        case .serverError(let responseCode): return "Server error \(responseCode)"
        case .underlyingError(let error): return error.localizedDescription
        case .unknown: return "Unknown error"
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

Inside your viewModel, then set the error you'll get (from your api etc.) and set it to your published error.

```
class YourViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person]
    @Published var error: NetworkError? // <- Set your error from your api here

    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        fetch()
    }

    func fetch() {
        api.people
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] (completion) in
                if case .failure(let error) = completion {
                    self?.error = error // An error occured
                }
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] (persons) in
            self?.onReceive(persons)
            self?.error = nil
        })
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }

   //...//
}
```

#### View

The published error will trigger the alert and you'll be able to present the errors' `localizedDescription` within the closure.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = YourViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.persons.first?.name ?? "N/A")
            .alert(item: self.$viewModel.error) { error in
                Alert(title: Text("Error"),
                      message: Text(error.localizedDescription),
                      dismissButton: .cancel())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to Create a UserState class and conform to the ObservableObject protocol.
Classes that conform to the ObservableObject protocol can use SwiftUI’s @Published property wrapper to automatically announce changes to properties, so that any views using the object get their body property reinvoked and stay in sync with their data.

```
//MARK:- Step:1 On SceneDelegate
// set environmentObject
let userState = UserState()
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(userState)


//MARK:- Step:2 Create UserState Class

class UserState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sessionExpired: Bool = false
}

//MARK:- Step:3 Create a ContentView

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Step:3 Create a userState EnvironmentObject
    @EnvironmentObject var userState: UserState
    @State private var isShowSecondView = false
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(),  isActive: $isShowSecondView) {
                
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    
                    Button("Show Second") {
                        isShowSecondView.toggle()
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Alert"), message: Text("Session Expired"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
                }
                .onChange(of:  userState.sessionExpired, perform: { value in // Step:4 in onChange we need to check sessionExpired or not
                    print("onChange")
                    if userState.sessionExpired {
                        showingAlert = true
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK:-

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userState: UserState
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            
            Button("Show Alert Message") {  // Step:5 -  Here I changed flag then alert will present
                userState.sessionExpired.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii @Jack you can accept this answer,I have tried and this works fine.